# Ruby:no such file to load -- coffee/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

I am a ruby novice.I created my first ruby on rails application which named "HelloRubyWeb" on my mac.Then "cd HelloRuby",But when I input the command "rails s" ,it returned the error log:

```
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require': no such file to load -- coffee/rails (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
from /Users/admin/Ruby/HelloRuby/config/application.rb:7
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:53
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6
```

Can any one help me? Very thanks.

Comment: Seems the required gem is not installed, can you post up your Gemfile?Make sure you run bundle install before you run rails s

Answer (score 1):

kasperite is probably right, in the terminal run:

`bundle` then run `rails s`

Post the errors you get if any.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but in my case it was because of the explicit coffee-rails version.

1) remove strictly set version for `coffee-rails` gem in `Gemfile`

2) run `bin/bundle`

3) run `bin/bundle update`

4) run `bin/rails s`

If you need explicitly set working version, just run `bin/bundle show 'coffee-rails'` and copy the version number from the terminal.